# How do I label of Field Group htab that has Hide as prefix?

Tags: entities

I have a custom module that I have coded in a Horizontal tabs (htabs) group and a number of individual tabs (htab) to break up my node form. When I open the add form the tabs are showing with the label having a prefix of "Hide". For example one of my tabs I have assigned the label as "Log Entries". When the form is opened it is showing as "Hide Log Entries".

I don't want the prefix and can't seem to find how to turn it off. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue.  I hade the collapse javascript included in my form alter function and it was adding in the "Hide" prefix to the labes.